# How to make Sendkeys accept special characters?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sendkeys

So i'm working on a Spambot, that basically spams the text I input into a textbox. For that i use:

Sendkeys.Send(Textbox1.text)

Sadly this doesn't support special characters like : ) < ^^ and stuff like that. I'd love to know how to make that work! :)

Comment: From the MSDN documentation: "The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of these characters, enclose it within braces ({})".

Comment: yeah, but i want it to work without having to specify them, because i'm simply using the textbox1.text as text...